# filename metod returns dot even the directory doesn't contain name of file

Tags: c++, path, filenames

I have problem that even if I write path without filename the method has_filename() returns true, and method filename() returns "." (dot).

```
using namespace std::experimental::filesystem;
path s;
std::cin >> s;                                                   //Here I write: "D:\Tests\" 
std::cout << "has filename: " << s.has_filename() <<std::endl;
std::cout <<"filename: " << s.filename() << std::endl;           //Here I get " . "
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: What compiler is this? Do you get a different result with the non-experimental std::filesystem?

Comment: VS c++ 2017 and I didn't try to get results from std::filesystem because VS doesn't see "std::filesystem" (I write #include <filesystem> but when I type "std::" there is no "filesystem" in hints